# How to process multiple files with pandoc?

Tags: bash, shell, parallelism, pandoc

files:

`$ ls
a.md
b.md
c.md
d.md
e.md`

Command: `pandoc file.md -f markdown file.pdf`

How would I parallely process two pandoc instances simulatneously? Possibly with `xargs` or `parallel`.

It would work like

Iteration/ cmd 1 / cmd 2

1 / pandoc a.md -f markdown a.pdf / pandoc b.md -f markdown b.pdf

2 / pandoc c.md -f markdown c.pdf / pandoc d.md -f markdown d.pdf

3 / pandoc e.md -f markdown e.pdf / pandoc f.md -f markdown f.pdf

4 / pandoc g.md -f markdown g.pdf / pandoc h.md -f markdown h.pdf

The files are randomly named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crudely,

```
#!/bin/sh

set -- *.md
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  pandoc "${1} -f markdown -o ${1%.md}.pdf" &
  shift
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]
  then
    pandoc "${1} -f markdown -o ${1%.md}.pdf" &
    shift
  fi
  wait
done
```

With xargs:

```
find . -type f -name '*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 -n2 -P2 -I{} pandoc {} -f markdown -o {}.pdf
```

you would have to rename them afterwards, as the above would result in files named a.md.pdf, b.md.pdf, etc. Note that to be safe with filenames, we're asking `find` to print null-separated filenames and asking `xargs` to read in null-separated input. Rename the files with:

```
for f in ./*.md.pdf; do mv -- "${f}" "${f%.md.pdf}.pdf"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
parallel pandoc {} -f markdown {.}.pdf ::: *.md
```

If you do not want to run one job per CPU thread, but want to force 2 in parallel:

```
parallel -j2 pandoc {} -f markdown {.}.pdf ::: *.md
```

You may want to spend 15 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 of the GNU Parallel book: http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html (Printed), https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 (Online).